# How to test the following async function in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing

code to test:

```
async showSuccess() {
  this.msgs.push({severity: 'success', summary: 'Success.'});
  await delay(1000);
  this.msgs = [];
}
```

here's the test I tried but await delay(1000) isn't covered and so isn't this.msgs = []

```
it('should show message', async() => {
        spyOn(component, 'showSuccess');
        component.showSuccess();
        expect(component.showSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

The method signature line is covered and the msgs being pushed is covered but not the last two lines.

Comment: Wait that show success was actually called before verifying it: `await component.showSuccess();`

Comment: Also, I want to quickly point out that with this test, you are essentially testing whether JavaScript executes some method when it is expected to execute that method. This test says nothing about your business logics, but just that JS is able to properly execute a random method.

Comment: @fjc I tried doing  it('should show message', () => {
        component.showSuccess();
        expect(component.msgs = []).toBeTruthy();
    }); but I got the same result.

Comment: You did not follow my recommendation to `await` `component.showSuccess()`. Also, you are expecting an assignment to a variable to be truthy. I don't know that that makes sense.

Comment: it('should show message', async() => {
        spyOn(component, 'showSuccess');
        component.showSuccess();
        expect(component.showSuccess).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

Answer (score 1):

So here's a complete Mocha/Chai based example that works and should show how you can implement a test like you are trying to:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const spies = require('chai-spies');
chai.use(spies);
const expect = chai.expect;

class ClassThatDoesStuff {

    randomArray = [];

    async doStuff() {
        console.log('Do stuff...');
        await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        this.randomArray.push('random entry');
        console.log('Done doing stuff');
    }
}

describe('Async Function Testing', () => {
    let objectThatDoesStuff = new ClassThatDoesStuff();

    it('should do things', async () => {
        const spy = chai.spy.on(objectThatDoesStuff, 'doStuff');
        await objectThatDoesStuff.doStuff();
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
        expect(objectThatDoesStuff.randomArray).to.contain('random entry');
    });
});
```

The most important point is: Before you assert that something was done by an asynchronous function, make sure to wait for that function to complete (in this case using `await objectThatDoesStuff.doStuff()`, in your case using `await component.showSuccess()`).